# 107095 : Error while Bulk insert in Microsoft SQL Server : All columns of the table must be specified in the Insert Bulk statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Error while Bulk insert in Microsoft SQL Server : 
SQL State : 37000, Native error = 1070905
All columns of the table must be specified in the Insert Bulk statement
Getting this error in one of our application which has the loader script.
Could anyone please explain what this error means and what are the reasons for this occurrence and solution.

Comment: What is the question, add some sample data, columns and expected output

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Please post the script and the table DDL, otherwise it's guessing.

Comment: We don't have access to the script. The script has been working fine. But in some instances, we are getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax diagram gives a hint on how to solve this:

> BULK INSERT       [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name .
>   ] [ table_name | view_name ]
>         FROM 'data_file'

The key idea is `view_name`.

Define a view that selects only the columns you want to import.  Then use that for the `bulk insert`.

I use this to set default values (as as identity columns) when importing data.